# Iterating over each child and apply a css property based on time passed

Tags: html, jquery, css

earlier I made a post: https://jsfiddle.net/dqj1x89z/

What I wanted to do is to apply a class on children elements based on the time that has passed, until now I managed to do something like that, besides what I already have there:

```
var childNodes = $('.tbi-phone-verification-loader').children();

function startTimer() {
        timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
        timePassed = timePassed += 1;
        timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
        document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(timeLeft);
        var intervalId = window.setInterval(function() {
            // childNodes.each(function(){
            //     $('.tbi-phone-verification-loader div:nth-child(i)').css("background","red");
            // })
            for(var i = 0; i <= childNodes.length; i++) {
            $('.tbi-phone-verification-loader div:nth-child('+i+')').css("background","red");
        }
        }, 10000)
        // var formattedTimeLabel = $('.base-timer__label').html();
        // formattedTimeLabel.replaceWith(`${formatTime(timeLeft)}`);

        //  if (timeLeft === 0) {
        //     onTimesUp();
        //     }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

I tried using for but it doesn't work, after 10 seconds all the circles are going red, I want every 10 seconds to fill a circle with the specified color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/ck02pozu/

## What I added

1. Made an array from all of the divs in the document: `let circles = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("div"))`.
2. Set a index for the array which will increased every-time 10 seconds have passed: `let circleIndex = 1` Note that I set it to 1 instead of 0 since you have another div which isn't a circle (at the start of the document).
3. Added a condition which will check if the seconds are divisible by 10 each time that the `formatTime` function have been called.
4. If the condition turns out the true, modify the current circle's background to red and increase `circleIndex` by +1.

## Getting the last animated circle

*This is after reading the OP's comment*

1. initialize an empty variable: `let lastCircleIndex`
2. Before modifying `circleIndex`'s value by +1: `lastCircleIndex = circleIndex`

Now check the console, `lastCircleIndex` will always be -1 away from `circleIndex`.

P.S: I edited the link in the above to include this last animated circle example.

Comment: Another question, if you don't mind you have any idea how to get the current element(the last animated element)?